# Flatpak asks for password several times

Tags: kubuntu, password, 23.10, flatpak

Using kubuntu 23.10, I enabled flatpak in Discover. Now everything works, including installing an app but everytime I tried, flatpak will ask me for my password several times (around a dozen times or so !) which seems related to the way flatpak install something (module to install ? password, repo to check ? password etc).
This is incredibly annoying.
Do you see any solution to this please ? At least some kind of restriction that will only ask for the password once ?

###### additional notes :

- I'm using flatpak without sudo for the current user. While I obvisously understand why flatpak will need my password, I can't really understand why it needs it more than a dozen of times (and I don't have this issue in Fedora, while using the same workflow)
- Using sudo (for flatpak install/update) solves the issue in a terminal but not in Discover.
- Is it a policykit behavior ?

Comment: did you consider [this resoource](https://kubuntu.org/news/flatpaks-and-kubuntu/) when installing Flatpaks on Kubuntu?

Comment: Thank you graham for your comment. If you're asking whether the packages needed are installed, then yes, since I enabled flatpak from kde discover (I double-checked just in case).